# Почему отклонённая правка?

Tags: обсуждение, отклонённые-правки

Я решил ответить на вопросы по метки MongoDB, где я видел, что общие ответы не были действительно хорошего качества или вопрос без ответа.

Примеры:

- [Поиск документов, значение ключа у которых не выходит за рамки полученного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/317059/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8)
- [Как оставить в массиве элемент с максимальным значением?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482049/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)
- [Как обновить несколько элементов в массиве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438537/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5)

Также я решил изменить вопрос с правой метки и улучшить заголовок, так что он может легко быть найдены с помощью поисковой системы. Так что я сталкивался с одним [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373493/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-mongodb), который я [ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491423/183327) и предлагал правки но [отклонённая правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/60093).

Так что я хочу знать, почему?

---

Кстати примите мои извинения за то я так с ошибками пишу. Я ещё не выучил русский язык из-за лени.:)

Comment: Ну формально: _Правка никак не делает сообщения более простым к прочтению, не упрощает его поиск, точность или доступность. Изменения абсолютно излишни или явно ухудшают читаемость._

Answer (score 6):

Привет. Я один из отклонивших эту правку. Изменения, вносимые ею, на мой взгляд неоднозначны: они "на грани" и назвать их "однозначно улучшающими" я не могу. По-хорошему, мне стоило бы *пропустить* эту правку и надеяться, что следующий человек её улучшит, но я в это не очень-то верил `:)`

Я рад, что вы заинтересовались отклонением и готовы бороться за улучшение. Итак, к делу.

- Заголовок:

  > Сортировка по сумме массивов в MongoDB *(было)*
  >   Как сортировать документы по количесво элементов в массиве? *(стало бы)*

  - Вы убрали из заголовка упоминание MongoDB. Зря. Да, MongoDB есть в тегах, но формулировка заголовка сама по себе стала иметь к реальному вопросу меньше отношения. Теперь в вопросе речь о каких-то абстрактных *документах*, тогда как упоминание MongoDB включает это, а при этом короче и точнее. В списке вопросов у вопроса стало меньше шансов привлечь соответствующих отвечающих. Но при этом вы поправили заблуждение автора о "сумме", когда реально важно "количество". Это хороший момент, но его редакторам сложновато заметить и не спутать с изменением смысла вопроса: стоит упомянуть об этом в пояснении к правке.
  - `количесво` — без комментариев. Извинения приняты, но правка есть правка, в исходном варианте таких ляпов не было :) Будь это единственная проблема, я бы это поправил и принял, но...
- Метки:

  - [сортировка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0) (и синоним [sort](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sort)) имеет очень косвенное отношение к вопросу: в нём не обсуждается сам "процесс упорядочивания коллекции элементов" (как гласит отрывок описания метки), сам процесс уже реализован в Монге и не обсуждается, вопрос лишь о способе его запуска. На мой взгляд, этой метке в этом вопросе не место.
  - Тег [mongodb-query](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-query), возможно, стоит уничтожить. Все вопросы с ним помечены меткой [mongodb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb), а означенная метка не добавляет в них контекста и не имеет описания. Я сначала подумал, мол, может, где-то есть модуль  с похожим названием, предназначенный для запросов? Поискал, не нашёл. Если вы можете сформулировать политику применения этой метки (и предложить правку с этим в описание метки), и она покажется случайным людям достаточно обоснованной, чтобы правку приняли, то у случайных редакторов (как минимум у меня) подозрений на счёт этой метки будет на порядок меньше.

Итого у меня сложилось ощущение о примерно равном объёме плюсов и минусов правки, из-за чего я её отклонил. Теперь, зная о проблемах, вы можете подготовить правку, которая всех устроит.

Возможно, перед этим вы захотите добавить описание к меткам, которые будете добавлять (если вы всё же считаете, что по запросам в Монгу нужна отдельная метка), чтобы их добавление выглядело осмысленным.

Comment: Есть разница межу `mongodb-query` , `mongodb` и `aggregation-framework`. я не изменил `сортировка` на `sort` это было автоматический. Тоже я должен был удалить `сортировка`. Что касается *количесво* хотел писать *количество*.  Но я бы не отклонил эту правку но улучшить её поскольку есть такая возможность.

Comment: @user3100115 "количествУ" тогда уж; собственно, к отклонению склонили в основном изменения в заголовке. AF касается скорее решений, чем вопроса, но ладно, эта метка к месту. А для чего предназначена метка [tag:mongodb-query], не расскажете? Возможно, её стоит, наконец, описать и использовать.