# Как реабилитироваться после бана?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, блокировка

Чувствуешь себя с гипсом на голове и начинаешь задумываться - а нужно ли так уж быть активным?

Как оставаться в форме, после блокировки?

Особенно расстраивает отсутствие предупреждений со стороны системы. Почему их нет?

Где советы по правилам поведения?

Как узнать подробности того проступка, по вине которого происходит блокировка? Где рекомендации именно по своей ситуации?

Как получать опыт поведения на сайте, если чуть оступился и тут же дают по рукам?

Comment: Вы про автоматический временный запрет на внесение правок? Просто вернитесь отклоненным правкам и посмотрите, почему именно их отклонили :) Но да, сам факт отсутствия уведомления об отклонении правки иногда напрягает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Несколько простых правил:

- **Если вашу правку отклонили по неясной вам причине — добейтесь ответа "почему"**, если не от отклонивших (как [бывает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2516/181100)), то хотя бы от сообщества (здесь, на Мете, или в чате), чтобы не допускать одну и ту же ошибку несколько раз. Что будет, если продолжать допускать её же, вы уже знаете :)
- **Если в метке нет описания, прежде чем ею хоть как-то пользоваться, стоит это описание предложить.** Основная угроза в несоблюдении этого в том, что если метку употребляют "как хотят", она перестаёт ограничивать конкретную тематику и теряет смысл. Как только это заметят, придётся приложить множество усилий, чтобы привести вопросы по ней в порядок. Чем раньше заметят, тем меньше работы.
- **Если тег без своих соседей теряет смысл, то он не нужен** (см. ["Смерть мета-тегов"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)).
- **Избегайте слишком общих меток.** В вопрос можно добавить до пяти меток. Каждая из этих меток должна выражать очень существенную часть *компетенций отвечающего*, чтобы этого количества хватало всегда. Нам же не нужна метка [компьютеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b) (надо же, её нет!) почти в каждом вопросе?

  - **Если описание есть, но нет рекомендаций к применению, это проблема.** У таких меток это *критическая* проблема, потому что люди её заметят и будут употреблять при малейшем касании. Хотя даже в более "узких" метках [всё бывает непросто](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2385/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-ruby-on-rails-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-ruby/2405#2405).
  - По этой причине добавление метки [файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b) в большинстве случаев бесполезно. Поскольку одной из первых задач многих языков является работа с файлами, любой, кто владеет неким языком, как правило владеет и этой его частью.

Answer (score 15):

У вас не бан, а только временный запрет на предлагаемые правки. Он включен автоматически системой, т.к. у вас было довольно много отклонённых правок за короткий промежуток времени. Запрет, насколько я вижу, продлится 5 дней.

Множество ваших правок были отклонены из-за того, что вы добавляли к вопросам обобщённые метки, которые практически не добавляли вопросу никакого смысла либо не соответствовали содержанию вопроса. Это может быть очевидным для более опытных участников, которые часто используют поиск, прочитали много вопросов и ориентируются в общей карте доступных меток. Если для вас это пока не очевидно - ничего страшного, вопрос опыта. Накопление этого самого опыта вы можете начать с [просмотра ваших отклоненных правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10791/titov-andrei?tab=activity) (как верно советует PashaPash).

> Где советы по правилам поведения?

Как ни удивительно, они находятся в разделе под названием [Справка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help). Он доступен через меню в верхней части страницы.

Также если вы хотите активно участвовать в работе сообщества, обязательно читайте Мету. Чтобы уточнить какой-то вопрос по поведению, задайте новый вопрос с меткой [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0).

> Как получать опыт поведения на сайте, если чуть оступился и тут же дают по рукам?

В том, что касается использования меток:

- **Обязательно читайте описания меток, которые добавляете**. Если у метки нет описания - это тревожный знак. Возможно, она не очень популярна и/или используется бессистемно.
- **Читайте популярные вопросы по каждой метке (с высоким рейтингом)**. Посмотрите, какие сопутствующие метки используются. Популярные вопросы получают много внимания, в том числе от опытных редакторов, так что в них обычно хорошо выбраны метки.
- **Читайте причины, по которым были отклонены ваши правки**. Если ситуация спорная, вы можете задать на Мете вопрос о конкретной предложенной правке: [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0),[предлагаемые-правки](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

> нужно ли так уж быть активным?

Качество важнее количества. Если уж предлагаете правку, старайтесь в ней исправить максимум недостатков вопроса. Если в вопросе уже почти нечего править и вы хотите только добавить одну-другую метку - то убедитесь, что они там действительно нужны.

Comment: Не согласен насчёт правок меток. Если правок не слишком много, и они реально по делу, а не для красоты (исправление неверно указанного языка, например), то такие правки полезны от юзера любого уровня.

Comment: Но ответ-то читать будут все. :)

Comment: @Discord исправил. Если есть чем- дополняйте.

Answer (score 12):

Дополню ответ Ника.

В движок сайта встроены предупреждения: если ваша предыдущая правка была отклонена, то при следующем редактировании вы увидите предупреждение. Однако это предупреждение может появиться, только если вы не делали правки на крейсерской скорости. В этом случае вы улетите в "правковый" бан раньше, чем увидите предупреждение.

Кроме того, мелкие предлагаемые правки в большой концентрации повышают вероятность, что высокореповым юзерам в очередях проверок надоест их разгребать. Одна мелкая правка, которая исправляет мелкий недочёт, но оставляет остальные, может пройти, но если такими правками завалить очередь, то разгребающие её скорее среагируют: "Ох, опять он!"

В целом, так как на сайте пост-модерация, то вы узнаёте о своих ошибках постфактум. Во многих случаях система пытается сообщать об ошибках, но если слишком увлечься какими-то действиями, то можно нарваться на ограничения. Соответственно, общая рекомендация: если вы недостаточно освоились с какой-то возможностью сайта, правила читать лень, а изучать традиции сайта — тем более, то старайтесь не слишком увлекаться. Тогда сайт будет успевать вас предупреждать, и можно будет избежать каких-либо последствий, даже если какие-то правила или рекомендации нарушены.

Так как многие нюансы далеко не очевидны, то не нужно бояться совершить ошибку. Если она единичная, обычно не будет никаких последствий.

Comment: Кстати да, про предупреждения я забыл написать. Отличное дополнение, спасибо.

Comment: Ну вот. Теперь будет меньше предлагаемых правок. И как мне значок собирать? Очередь всегда пуста. Редко когда удаётся в неделю 2-3 правки принять. Я их даже смотреть перестал - лишь бы успеть жамкнуть пока не пропало( [meta-tag:нытьё]

Comment: Любопытен выбор автора в этом вопросе. )